# Cannot use object of type MongoCursor as array

Tags: php, mongodb

I have this error when I try to use my php file

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type MongoCursor as array in

Part of my code :

```
<?php
try {
           $connection = new MongoClient();
           $database   = $connection->selectDB('test');
           $collection = $database->selectCollection('articles');
         } Catch(MongoException $e) {
           die("Failed to connect to database ".$e->getMessage());
}
         $cursor = $collection->find();

       ?>

<?php session_start();

?>

<html>

<p> test1 </p>

<p> test </p>



 <h3> Comment the photo </h3>

       <?php foreach($cursor['comments'] as $comment):
```

I think error is due to :
-  `<?php foreach($cursor['comments'] as $comment):` or  `$cursor = $collection->find();`

Answer (score 2):

Convert `$cursor` to Array:

```
$elements = $cursor->toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try this one it convert your mango cursor object to array($data). 
then you can access data you want.


$data = array();
while($cursor->hasNext())
            {
                $cursor->next();
                $temp = array();
                $temp = $cursor->current();
                array_push($data, $temp);
            }
```

var_dump($data);

Comment: it converts your mongo cursor output from find query to array. then you can  access data in foreach.

Comment: I still have no comment that appears on the page but comments are in the database

Comment: hasNext() is not a function now.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `$cursor['comments']` and do a loop like this:

```
<?php
    foreach ($cursor as $comment) {
       ?>
     <p> <?php echo $comment['name']; ?>  </p>
<?php   
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: you are using `$comment` outside foreach loop ?

Comment: there is no comment appears on the page

Comment: `null` value is stored in article. Go to your mongodb console and edit your document.

Comment: I am starting with mongodb , what I should write on console ?

Comment: after update { "_id" : ObjectId("552a56fd0faaf2bd03b7acda"), "text" : "after update", "comment_name" : "Anis", "comment_email" : "anis@laposte.com" }

Comment: now i dont have comments on my page with this code :     <?php foreach ($cursor as $comment) { 
       ?>
   
   <p> <?php echo $comment['comment_name'].'says...'; ?> </p>
    
  <p> <?php  echo $comment['comment'];  
}
?>

Answer (score -1):

Command:

```
$cursor = $collection->find();
```

gives you an array (`$cursor = $collection->findOne()` - gives you one element).

If you want to loop over comments then you have to use:

```
foreach($cursor as $oneElement) {
    foreach($oneElement['comments'] as $comment) {
        //some code
    } 
}
```

Comment: [#find](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-find/#return-values) is the one that returns a cursor, [#findOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-findOne/#return-values) returns an array.